# qt5.3 qml window with FramelessWindowHint on mac can't showMinimized and showMaximized,how to fix?

Tags: macos, qml, qt5.3

```
Window {
id: rootWindow
objectName: "rootWindow"
visible: true
width: 980
height: 650
flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint|Qt.MacWindowToolBarButtonHint|Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint|Qt.WindowMaximizeButtonHint

property bool fullscreen: false
}
```

this window can't showMinimized and showMaximized on macosx 10.9,How to fix?
Thanks

Comment: You use a QQuickView or something for launching your QML code ?

Comment: Use QQmlApplicationEngine:`QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///main.qml")));`